# Extract the Folder Names and Levels from paths SQL Server / ORACLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Assuming I have a dataset like this:

[image: Source Data]

What I need to do is to make a dataset like this in SQL Server. Any help is appreciated:

[image: Expected Output]

Code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/SjGbD6Cc

```
CREATE TABLE  "TABLE1" ("FOLDER_ID" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) ,"FOLDER_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) , "PATH" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) ); 

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('1','Folder1','');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('2','Folder1_1','Folder1/Folder1_1');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('3','Folder1_1_1','Folder1/Folder1_1/Folder1_1_1');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('4','Folder1_2','Folder1/Folder1_2');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('5','Folder1_2_1','Folder1/Folder1_2/Folder1_2_1');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('6','Folder1_2_2','Folder1/Folder1_2/Folder1_2_2');
```

Comment: Your question is tagged SQL Server, but your sample code is Oracle.  What database are you really using?

Comment: Just to mention: your first row breaks the rule of "path ends with current folder name", which is true for all other folders and for ls/DIR command output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

**Example**

```
Select A.Folder_ID
      ,A.Folder_Name
      ,Parent_Folder = Pos2
      ,Lvl           = len(Path)-len(replace(Path,'/',''))
 From Table1 A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = reverse(trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')))
                      ,Pos2 = reverse(trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')))
                 From  ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(reverse(Path),'"','\"'),'/','","')+'"]' ) ) A(S)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Folder_ID   Folder_Name     Parent_Folder   Lvl
1           Folder1         NULL            0
2           Folder1_1       Folder1         1
3           Folder1_1_1     Folder1_1       2
4           Folder1_2       Folder1         1
5           Folder1_2_1     Folder1_2       2
6           Folder1_2_2     Folder1_2       2
```

Comment: Reading your answers one after the other, I am starting to realize that JSON is often an efficient and simple approach at string parsing problems in SQL Server...

Comment: @GMB I'm finding that too.    It was a BIG day when they introduced JSON  :)

Comment: Now if only they were to provide proper support for string operations, such as splitting (with ordinality!), regexes, and so on, that would be even nicer! SQL Server is really late in that regard.

Comment: @GMB  AMEN ! ! ! !

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible for you, if you can attach the way to do in oracle also. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AradhyaKumar Not an Oracle guy.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for oracle also, I will post.
Solution is very straightforward thanks to [`CONNECT BY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/queries003.htm) feature that nicely fits for such task:

```
with TABLE1 as (
  select '1' as "FOLDER_ID",'Folder1' as "FOLDER_NAME",'' as "PATH" from dual union 
  select '2','Folder1_1','Folder1/Folder1_1' from dual union 
  select '3','Folder1_1_1','Folder1/Folder1_1/Folder1_1_1' from dual union 
  select '4','Folder1_2','Folder1/Folder1_2' from dual union 
  select '5','Folder1_2_1','Folder1/Folder1_2/Folder1_2_1' from dual union 
  select '6','Folder1_2_2','Folder1/Folder1_2/Folder1_2_2' from dual
)
, nvled as (
  select folder_id, folder_name, nvl(path, folder_name) as path
  from table1
)
select
  folder_id
  , folder_name
  , prior folder_name as parent
  , level - 1 as lvl
  , path
from nvled
connect by regexp_replace(path, '/' || folder_name || '$', '') = prior path
  and path != folder_name
start with path = folder_name
```

Output:

```
FOLDER_ID    FOLDER_NAME    PARENT       LVL  PATH
1            Folder1                     0    Folder1
2            Folder1_1      Folder1      1    Folder1/Folder1_1
3            Folder1_1_1    Folder1_1    2    Folder1/Folder1_1/Folder1_1_1
4            Folder1_2      Folder1      1    Folder1/Folder1_2
5            Folder1_2_1    Folder1_2    2    Folder1/Folder1_2/Folder1_2_1
6            Folder1_2_2    Folder1_2    2    Folder1/Folder1_2/Folder1_2_2
```